# admob banner and interstitial advertising the application closes when you open it

Tags: android-studio

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.inabdev.productsapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar' //spots moving dialog
    implementation 'com.github.MdFarhanRaja:SearchableSpinner:2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'
}
```

at the time of adding implementation

```
com.google.android.gms: play-services-ads: 19.0.1
```

when compiler no longer april application closes automatically.

Comment: Check your formatting

Comment: Please add more description details to your post and  clarify what you mean by "when compiler no longer april application closes automatically." line